# Cannot debug Azure Function with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, solution

The function project (.csproj) where created in a solution. I deleted the solution and tried to load the function project in another solution.

Result: When I press F5 to debug, Visual Studio do not recognize it as an Azure Function.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I tell Visual Studio this project is an Azure Function and not a regular class librairy?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Solution change is not the issue.

The nuget package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions disapeared (probably a bad manipulation).

I re-add it and it worked.